# Make a function to find the value of Y according to X value

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Hello everybody,

```
data <- structure(list(nb_p = c(5, 35, 65, 95, 125, 155, 185, 215, 245, 
        275, 305, 335, 365, 395, 425, 455, 485, 515, 545, 575), nb_obs = c(0.467687074829932, 
        2.96031746031746, 4.97619047619048, 6.58134920634921, 7.84126984126984, 
        8.80328798185941, 9.5187074829932, 10.0325963718821, 10.3543083900227, 
        10.5379818594104, 10.5969387755102, 10.5603741496599, 10.4348072562358, 
        10.2539682539683, 10.0011337868481, 9.72675736961451, 9.41043083900227, 
        9.07568027210884, 8.72534013605442, 8.36649659863946), inf90 = c(0.440447845804989, 
        2.87573696145125, 4.85711451247166, 6.44331065759637, 7.68307823129252, 
        8.6342970521542, 9.31232993197279, 9.80609410430839, 10.1116496598639, 
        10.2891156462585, 10.346768707483, 10.2799886621315, 10.1522675736961, 
        9.95918367346939, 9.6920918367347, 9.41646825396825, 9.08503401360544, 
        8.75396825396825, 8.40578231292517, 8.01924603174603), sup90 = c(0.495493197278912, 
        3.05045351473923, 5.09481292517007, 6.73137755102041, 8.01360544217687, 
        8.98642290249433, 9.71496598639456, 10.2392573696145, 10.587358276644, 
        10.7700396825397, 10.8317176870748, 10.8084183673469, 10.6950396825397, 
        10.5011904761905, 10.2920068027211, 10.0045918367347, 9.70646258503401, 
        9.3702380952381, 9.01590136054422, 8.66785714285714)), row.names = c(NA, 
        -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My plot :

```
g <- ggplot(data)
g + geom_ribbon(aes(x = nb_p, ymin = inf90, ymax = sup90), fill = "yellow") +
     geom_line(aes(x = nb_p, y =nb_obs)) + theme_bw()
```

I would like to do two things please.
First, create a function that (i) when I give the "nb_p" it gives me a "nb_obs" and (ii) and vice versa.
Secondly, I would like that when I give a "nb_p", draw a line (abbline) vertical "nb_p" and the line "nb_obs" corresponding horizontal. Thx !

Comment: Hi Thomas, I realize you may be stuck on this problem, but SO was not designed to be a free code service. If you could edit your question to include things you have tried so far this would allow more people to help you with where you are stuck. Also great job of including some workable data using `dput()`, if you could also include an example of expected output (even using psuedocode) that would also allow more users to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one is more tricky than you know it. The reason is that both `nb_p` and `nb_obs` are doubles. The problem is as follows: you print the data, and see the following:

```
    nb_p nb_obs  inf90  sup90
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     5  0.468  0.440  0.495
 2    35  2.96   2.88   3.05 
 3    65  4.98   4.86   5.09
```

Say you wish to have the `nb_p` corresponding to `nb_obs == 2.96`. Seems easy enough:

```
> data %>% filter(nb_obs == 2.96) %>% pull(nb_p)
numeric(0)
```

Bummer! The problem is that you should never use `==` or `%in%` to compare doubles, because computers do not have infinite precision and you are always rounding up one way or the other. You could solve it for `nb_p` by converting the data to integer:

```
data$nb_p <- as.integer(data$nb_p)
```

It would make much more sense to get the given numbers based on the *row number*:

```
data %>% slice(2) %>% pull(nb_p)
data %>% slice(2) %>% pull(nb_obs)
```

I don't see much of a need of a special function to do this, though, but OK:

```
p2obs <- function(data, p) {
   data %>% filter(nb_p == p) %>% pull(nb_obs)
}
```

This one is a little bit more complicated because of the problem I mentioned before.

```
obs2p <- function(data, obs, eps=0.01) {
    data %>% filter(abs(nb_obs - obs) < eps) %>% pull(nb_p)

}
```

Regarding your second question.

g <- ggplot(data)
g <- g + geom_ribbon(aes(x = nb_p, ymin = inf90, ymax = sup90), fill = "yellow") +
     geom_line(aes(x = nb_p, y =nb_obs)) + theme_bw()

We use `geom_vline` and `geom_hline`.

```
 with_lines <- function(data, g, p) {
    obs <- p2obs(data, p)
    g + geom_vline(xintercept=p) + geom_hline(yintercept=obs)
 }
```

For example

```
with_lines(data, g, 185)
```

Comment: Thx for your explication ! Your solution works very well in the range of my data.  
I'm afraid of complicating my question too much. But my values ​​come in an interval. But the line of my plot is continuous. In the min-max range, to ask for 10 nb_p or 29 nb_p? Same for n_obs, for example 10 nb_obs. But I have the impression that it is too complicated (it would be necessary to model the curve ...). 
But I have several graphics like that and I will be able to illustrate the difference between it with your function! Thanks again !

Comment: I strongly suggest that you try first yourself, then ask another question describing your problem in detail. Nothing is ever too complicated, but you need to explain your problem very clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Make a function that just mirrors whatever model you are trying to fit (you need to do this on your own to get your various coefficients, `lm` is just a linear regression and this doesn't look linear but the principle will be the same).

```
model<-(lm(nb_p~nb_obs))
pfobs<-function(nb_obs){round(coefficients(model)[1],2)+coefficients(model)[-1]*nb_obs}
pfobs(11)
```

Then add a line using that function

```
g + geom_ribbon(aes(x = nb_p, ymin = inf90, ymax = sup90), fill = "yellow") +
  geom_line(aes(x = nb_p, y =nb_obs)) + theme_bw()+
  geom_vline(xintercept = pfobs(11))
```

Repeat for the y axis variable.

Comment: Hi, thx you for your post, it's look like what I want. It would have been easier with graph paper and a ruler.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to the first part of your question.

```
    f <- function(nb_p) {
      result = data[which(data$nb_p == nb_p), 'nb_obs']
      return (ifelse(length(result[[1]]) == 0, NaN, result))
    }
```